# IdentityServer4 + asp.net core API: cannot access userinfo endpoint

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 + asp.net core API. In client side I use angular-cli.

This is client defined:
[image]

This is resources defined:
[image]

This is test users defined:
[image]

in ConfigServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        // Enable CORS.
        CorsPolicyBuilder corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowCredentials();
        services.AddCors(opts =>
        {
            opts.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", corsBuilder.Build());
        });

        services.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(container);
        // identityserver4 configuration
        services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Resources.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Resources.GetApiResources())
                .AddTestUsers(Users.Get());

        // Zip response
        services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(opts => opts.Level = CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
        {
            opts.EnableForHttps = false;
            opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
                new[]
                {
                    "image/svg+xml",
                    "application/atom+xml"
                });
            opts.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
        });

        // Adds services required for using options.
        services.AddOptions();

        // Register the IConfiguration instance which MyOptions binds against.
        services.Configure<ConfigModel>(Configuration);
    }
```

This is config:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<ConfigModel> optionsAccessor)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));
        var url = optionsAccessor.Value.SystemConfig.Authority;
        app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = url,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            ApiName = Definitions.WebApiScope/*,
            AllowedScopes = { Definitions.WebApiScope }*/
        });
        app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
        app.UseResponseCompression();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

        // register service
        //DependencyRegistrator.RegisterServices(app, container);
        //container.Verify();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

I can use token endpoint to retrieve access_token, and I use this for request userinfo endpoint. This is header:

```
authJsonHeaders() {
const header = new Headers();
header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
header.append('Accept', 'application/json');
header.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
return header;
```

}

But I always get error `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405`

What're my missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure it's not your `OPTIONS` request that isn't getting the preflight? Add a `OPTIONS` endpoint and disable auth on it.

Comment: aren't you suppose to set access_token here  header.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + **localStorage.getItem('id_token'))**;....??

Comment: @WesleyCoetzee: thank you for replying. How do we disable auth on it?

Comment: I mean that I cannot get userinfo by http://mydomain/connect/userinfo with above header and authentication.

Comment: @jack.pop add `[AllowAnonymous]` above the endpoint

Comment: that's the endpoint supported by identityserver4. How can we set [AllowAnonymous] above the endpoint?

Comment: Finnaly, I can make it working myself by putting 
app.UseCors("default"); before app.UseIdentityServer(); in Configure method